# Ruby activerecord seems to ignore set_table_name

Tags: ruby, activerecord, schema

I'm running ruby on Mac OSX 10.6.4, using Ruby 1.8 and activerecord 2.3.8.  I'm running the following code inside of NetBeans 6.9 but I'm using the ruby interpreter from 10.6

I have the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
(
    :adapter=> "mysql",
    :host => "localhost",
    :username => "test",
)

class Test_information < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name = "test_information"
end

record = Test_information.find(:first)
```

When the code runs I get an error that it can't find the table test_informations.  There is a table called test_information and I can query it...but not with activerecord.

Is there some magic incantation that I have to use with set_table_name?  I was under the impression that it was pretty straightforward to use an existing schema with activerecord...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

--Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is `set_table_name "test_information"` (no equals sign)

Comment: Doh!  Pays to think a little more...

Thanks again for you help.

Answer (score 2):

set_table_name is a method so you need to say

```
set_table_name "test_information"
```

Pass as parameter not as an assignment

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...if I include either of the following lines after the class definition it works great.

```
Test_Information.pluralize_table_names = false
Test_Information.set_table_name("test_information")
```

Is there some reason why it doesn't work inside the class definition?